# How to fix this error calling getter in view from controller in flutter using GetX

Tags: flutter, dart, model-view-controller, getter, flutter-getx

I got this error after following a tutorial.

[image]

**Note: in the screenshot I tired _answersModel and answersModel but none worked.**

---

Here is my Controller:

[image]

---

Then Here is my Model

[image]

---

**How can I get rid of this error?**

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Changing _answersModel to answersModel would fix your issue.**

Also calling AnswersController.answersModel doesn't work because answersModel is not a static field, I think you meant call **answersController.answersModel**

**Note:**
Adding an underscore to a class file is making it private field in dart/flutter which means it can't be accessed in another file.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `_answersModel` in `AnswersController` public by removing `_` in the begging of name, like `answersModel`.

Why in the tutorial it works? I may guess that in the tutorial the `AnswersController` in the same file in `main.dart`.

Comment: "Make the _answersModel in AnswersController public by removing _ in the begging of name, like answersModel."

I have already done that but didn't work