# Trying to debug in flutter I go error from obx how to fix it

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-getx, flutter-debug

I have a code which can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73308453/how-to-fix-this-error-calling-getter-in-view-from-controller-in-flutter-using-ge?answertab=modifieddesc#tab-top)

trying to debug it I got this error, I don't know where I made mistake in the Obx function as started by flutter.

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @Omkar76 noted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap the Scaffold into Obx if you need to update the state on whole widget tree or the ListTile to Update the specific widget.

Comment: I have already wrapped it as you can see

Comment: This is the code

`return Scaffold(
        body: Obx(
      () => ListView.builder(
          itemCount: answersController.answersModel?.assets?.length ?? 0,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(answersController.answersModel?.assets![index].name ??
                  'no desc'),
            );
          }),
    ));`

Comment: No, can't see it. You wrap the ListView.builder() not the Scaffold.